# question about using arm64 hardware debug registers in EL1 level

Tags: exception, debugging, kernel, breakpoints, arm64

I'm debugging a task stack base step bug of a rtos operation system running in aarch64 EL1, the addr is 4k aligned, like: 0xFFFFxxxx8000. i tried bellow debugging code to expect that when i write any data to this addr, exception shell be catched and then I can analysis the calltrace. However, in testing to force data to this addr, nothing happend.

```
uint32_t mdscr, enable = 0;
uint64_t addr, ctrl;

/*enable MDE and KDE */
enable = DBG_MDSCR_MDE | DBG_MDSCR_KDE;
asm volatile("mrs %0, mdscr_el1" : "=r" (mdscr));
mdscr |= enable;
asm volatile("msr mdscr_el1, %0" :: "r" (mdscr));

#define ARM_BREAKPOINT_LEN_8    0xff
#define ARM_BREAKPOINT_STORE    2
#define AARCH64_BREAKPOINT_EL1  1

addr = task->stack_base;
ctrl = (ARM_BREAKPOINT_LEN_8<<5) | (ARM_BREAKPOINT_STORE<<3) | (AARCH64_BREAKPOINT_EL1<<1 | 1);
asm volatile("msr dbgbvr0_el1, %0" :: "r" (addr));
asm volatile("msr dbgbcr0_el1, %0" :: "r" (ctrl));
asm volatile("msr dbgwvr0_el1, %0" :: "r" (addr));
asm volatile("msr dbgwcr0_el1, %0" :: "r" (ctrl));

uint8_t cur_cpu_id = cpu_cur_get();
printk("addr %p is watched on cpu %d\n", cur_cpu_id);

............................................................

//in test case I write date to this task stack base directly:

uint8_t cur_cpu_id = cpu_cur_get();
printk("test writing addr %p on cpu %d\n", cur_cpu_id);
task->stack_base = -1;
```

I'm sure that the cur_cpu_id is always 0, and the exception handler (el0 and el1) is ok, software breakpoint like "BRK" in this kernel works well and exception can be catched as expected, but the hardware debugging test code above never makes a exception.

I tried to search from webs but got nothing.